# Elixir thread-safe access to json file?

Tags: elixir

I have multiple tasks trying to read and then update .json file at the same time. In database scenario I would just put lock on a row... Can something similar be done with a file?

I know that this can be solved via genserver handle_call, do I have any easier option?

Comment: A GenServer or any kind of "wrapper" interface around the JSON access would be the way to go in Elixir. If you have something else in mind, can you provide an example of the interface you were thinking of?

Comment: What could be _easier_, than a `GenServer.handle_call`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no mechanism for putting a lock on a specific line of a file and there is no elixir json library I know of that would let you put a lock on a specific element in a json structure. You'd have to build your own elixir representation of the data and do something like "checkout" and "checkin" an element from the structure or wrap each sub piece of the structure in a process.

Also it would behoove you to forget the word thread when writing elixir/erlang/otp. We use processes.

Answer (score 0):

There really is not reason not to use a GenServer to "wrap" this file - the effort is very low and the benefits are large:

1. You can build an abstraction about the JSON file modifications, which will very likely clean up your code;
2. GenServer executions are serialized, removing your locking problem;
3. You build a foundation that readies you for more advanced usage (say, an async call with callback when the JSON editing is complete).

And I'm sure I can come up with more. When starting Elixir, GenServer feels a bit heavyweight (it does have a bit more boilerplate); after a while, the question becomes not "do I wrap this in a GenServer?" but "how will the GenServer for this bit look like?" - it becomes natural.